# How to start WebGIS for broke people?

Tags: postgis

I want to make a web GIS system. I will be graduating in 3 months and have time on my hands before going for interviews. if i can build something then i can show it off in the interviews and hopefully make me stand out. 
However how do i go about this with zero budget but i have lots of public data from university?

Answer (score -1):

[MapsJS](http://mapsjs.com/examples.html) and the Express version of [MapDotNet](http://www.mapdotnet.com/index.php/developers-center/60-day-trial-downloads) (free trial downgrades to Express- only two worker threads, plenty for light traffic- after 60 days.)